What's the name of this horror movie of the 00's?
I saw this movie the same week that SAW I and I thought that these two were the greatest horror/suspense movies of those years, because of the respective plot twists. This movie is also of the 00's. 
It takes place in a psychiatric hospital. A student of medicine or psychology arrives there, and suddenly the inmates start to die, as well as the doctors. I believe that they think that a patient of a specific room is committing the murders. 
At the end it results that there is no one in that room. The plot twist is that the student is the murderer. I also remember that a patient is a nymphomaniac. For years, I used to think that the student was Cyllian Murphy, so I don't really know if the main character looks like him or I want to think that.

Is it Madhouse (2004 film)



Only change is that the hero is intern not student, rest match with your description. And he had Dissociative identity disorder and the person he talks to in the psycho-ward cell was his second personality.
I don't know how you mixed Joshua Leonard with  Cyllian Murphy, he looks like this in the film :

